# Keycloak server in docker fails to start in standalone mode?

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

Well, as the title suggests, this is more of an issue record. I was trying to follow the instructions on this [README](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/README.md) file of Keycloak docker server images, but encountered a few blockers.

After pulling the image, below command to start a standalone instance failed.

```bash
docker run jboss/keycloak
```

The error stack trace:

```bash
-b 0.0.0.0
=========================================================================

  Using PostgreSQL database

=========================================================================

...

04:45:06,084 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-5) Converted [2] config entries and added [4] replacements
04:45:06,096 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0113: '' is an invalid value for parameter user-name. Values must have a minimum length of 1 characters"
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:382)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/KeycloakDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.KeycloakDS
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
...
```

I was wondering how it uses a PostgreSQL database, and assumed it might spin up its own instance. But the error looks like it has a problem connecting to the database.

Changing to the embedded H2 DB made it work.

`docker run -e DB_VENDOR="h2" --name docker-keycloak-h2 jboss/keycloak`

The [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/7d3c78065fc8ae437b246fa9ce8c65a76d69ce76/server/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh#L96) file shows that it uses below logic to determine what DB to use.

```bash
if (getent hosts postgres &>/dev/null); then
        export DB_VENDOR="postgres"
...
```

And further down the flow, this [change-database.cli](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/7d3c78065fc8ae437b246fa9ce8c65a76d69ce76/server/tools/cli/databases/postgres/change-database.cli#L2) file indicates that it's actually expecting a running PostgreSQL instance to use.

```bash
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_ADDR:postgres}:${env.DB_PORT:5432}/${env.DB_DATABASE:keycloak}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}
```

So I began wondering how PostgreSQL was chosen as a default initially. Executing below commands in a running Keycloak docker container revealed some interesting things.

```bash
[root@71961b81189c bin]# getent hosts postgres
69.172.201.153  postgres.mbox.com
[root@71961b81189c bin]# echo $?
0
```

Not sure what this `postgres.mbox.com` is but apparently it's not an expected PostgreSQL server to be resolved by `getent`. Not sure whether this is a recent linux issue either. The `hosts` entry in the Name Service Switch Configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like below inside the container.

```bash
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

It is the `dns` data source that resolved `postgres` to `postgres.mbox.com`.

---

This is why the DB vendor determination logic failed which eventually caused the container failing to start. The instructions on this README file do not work as of the day this post is published.

Below are the working commands to start a Keycloak server in docker properly with PostgreSQL as the database.

```bash
docker network create keycloak-network

docker run -d --name postgres --net keycloak-network -e POSTGRES_DB=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres

docker run --name docker-keycloak-postgres --net keycloak-network -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=password jboss/keycloak
```

Comment: Running into the same issue. The last docker run command you mentioned however works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @jwi Yes, it is because there is a running postgres instance that can be detected by the startup script.

Comment: Thank you so much for the workaround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem no longer occurs now. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: @AksimElnik I have provided a workaround in the original post. You can try that to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue. As it turned out, the key to the solution was the missing parameter "DB_USER=keycloak".

The Application tried to authenticate against the database using the username ''. This was indicated by the first error message.

```
WFLYCTL0113: '' is an invalid value for parameter user-name
```

Possibly the 4.x and 5.0.0 versions set the default user name to "keycloak" which was no longer the case in 6.0.0.

After adding the parameter DB_USER=keycloak to the list of environment variables, keycloak started up without any problems.

Comment: I feel like this is a different issue. To solve the exact problem as mentioned in the original post, we just need to explicitly specify the DB to be used, instead of leaving it to Keycloak to check.

Comment: This comment have helped me with version 3.4.3.Final. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had an interesting observation to this issue, even in version 7.0.0. Alike the author mentions, postgres is selected if the host can resolve.

```
$ getent hosts postgres
$ 92.242.140.21
```

What I've noticed is that if I issue a ping command at anything bizzare, even foobar, it evaluates to that same ip address. Example:

```
$ ping foobar
$ PING foobar (92.242.140.21): 56 data bytes
```

It seems that my ISP sends everything to a common endspace. I've solved the problem by using the -e DB_VENDOR=h2, to select the h2 db, and then had no issues. Alternatively, you can always spin up your own postgres version, or point to a legitimate endpoint. ( Not something fake provided by your ISP for DNS error handling )